# Counting words in a list

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I am trying to count the frequency of a word in a list, using the `len()` but it's not working, I created a car list and then using random I am basically printing the cars 20 times, so the random is creating 20 random cars, but now I am trying to count how many times each car is being created, but its not working it just displays 5, 20 times?

```
carslist =["aston martin", "nissan", "nobel", "Porsche", "merc"] 
randomGen = map(lambda x : random.randint(0,5), range(20))
cars= map(lambda i: carslist[i], randomGen)
print cars

#not working, trying to count how many times each car is being printed
lengths = map (lambda x: len(carsList), cars)
print lengths
```

Comment: Python 2: `map(lambda x: y, z)` → `[y for x in z]`

Comment: I am trying to do it with either len or reduce

Comment: Well, don’t. Use a [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: Are `merc` and `ford` the same car in your definition? Both names have 4 characters...

Comment: Also, `random.randint(a,b)` gives values from a to b inclusive. I don't think you want to include 5 as a possible index in randomGen

Answer (score 0):

We'll have a list: `cars = ['nissan','nobel','nobel', 'porsche', 'merc', 'merc', 'porsche', 'aston martin']`

One way to solve this problem is to iterate over the list. We'll initialize a dictionary, `carCounts`, that keeps track of how many times each car appears

```
carCounts = defaultdict(int)
for car in cars:
  carCounts[car] += 1
print carCounts
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Counter`

```
carslist = ["aston martin", "nissan", "nobel", "Porsche", "merc"] 
randomGen = map(lambda x: random.randint(0, 4), range(20))
cars = map(lambda i: carslist[i], randomGen)

from collections import Counter
lengths = Counter(cars)
print lengths
# Counter({'merc': 6, 'nissan': 4, 'nobel': 4, 'Porsche': 3, 'aston martin': 3})
```